# get last/current Tuesday date in Teradata based on day count of current week

Tags: date, teradata

How to get last Tuesday date in Teradata if (day of week< 2)
else current Tuesday date (if day of week >2)

E.g day of week= 2 for today(15 October 2018) then get last Tuesday's date(09/10/2018)

for day of week> 2(17th October 2018) get this week Tuesday (16/10/2018)

i want to do it using exact method of Teradata preferably

I have below sql code

```
DECLARE @StartDt AS  DATE;
DECLARE @EndDt AS  DATE;
DECLARE @Dt AS  DATE;
select @RDt=CASE WHEN CAST(DATEPART(DW,GETDATE()) AS INT) > 2 
        THEN 
        CAST(DATEADD(WK, DATEDIFF(WK,0,GETDATE()), 1) AS DATE)
        ELSE  
         CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,6,GETDATE()),1),107) END

select @StartDt=CAST(DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,6,@Dt),0) AS DATE) 
select @EndDt=CAST(DATEADD(WK,DATEDIFF(WK,6,@Dt),6) AS DATE)
```

and i need equivalent teradata code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's `next_day` to get the following weekday, applying some logic results in:

```
Next_Day(calendar_date - 7, 'tuesday')
```